# Run SSL Certificate in IIS and Node JS

Tags: node.js, iis, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012

I have a windows server 2012 with a SSL Certificate running in IIS.
I have a Node JS app deployed on that server too, i'm using [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) to manage this project, but, I need to use this project with https too.

How I can do this?

Previously I tried to re-key the certificate with Open SSL following the steps of this link:
[Setting up real SSL with Node JS](http://www.backwardcompatible.net/155-Setting-up-real-SSL-Nodejs-Express)

Everything is ok, but when I re-key the certificate with the .csr generated by openSSL, my certificate on IIS stop working.

How can I achieve this?

I'm using GoDaddy for the SSL certificate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're essentially trying to use the same certificate on two different web servers?  Presumably they serve to different domains? (e.g. a.mydomain.com, b.mydomain,.com).

If their base domain is the same you can look into getting a certificate issued that has a wildcarded domain (*.mydomain.com). If your registrar doesn't support this, or if your domains are totally different and not related, then you need two different certificates.

Comment: No, sorry if I didn't explain myself well.
I want to put SSL on the same server, only one app is managed by IIS (developed in C #) and another app is managed by PM2 (Node JS app). They are both in the same domain, for example:
www.mydomain.com/CsharpAPP managed by IIS
Y
www.mydomain.com/NodeJSAPP managed by pm2.

I want to use the same certificate to use https in both applications.

Comment: You'll likely have to have something in front of the web servers that knows how to route "/CharpApp' and "/NodeJSApp" to the correct web server (some sort of load balancer or reverse proxy like nginx).  To make it simpler I would probably do as I suggest, have two subdomains (a.mydomain..., b.mydomain) and then create a wildcard certificate (*.mydomain.com) that can be attached to both web servers/sites.  I'm sure you can route by URL like you want, but you almost certainly will need to have some sort of web router or load balancer